# How to get a nicely formatted PHP Web Service response?

Tags: php, wsdl

I called an API like this:

```
$service = new Class_Service();

$parameters = new GetClasses();
$parameters->Request = new GetClassesRequest();

$parameters->Request->SourceCredentials = new SourceCredentials();
$parameters->Request->SourceCredentials->SourceName = "Name";
$parameters->Request->SourceCredentials->Password = "Pass";
$parameters->Request->SourceCredentials->SiteIDs = array(
12
);

$classes = $service->GetClasses($parameters);

var_dump($classes);
```

And received a response like this:

```
object(GetClassesResponse)#7 (1) { 
  ["GetClassesResult"]=> 
    object(GetClassesResult)#8 (6 {
      ["Classes"]=> 
        object(stdClass)#9 (1) { 
          ["Class"]=> array(25) { 
            [0]=> object(Mi_Class)#10 (21) {
               ["ClassScheduleID"]=> int(15)
               ["Visits"]=> NULL
               ["Clients"]=> NULL 
               ["Location"]=> object(Location)#11 (30) { 
                 ["BusinessID"]=> NULL
                 ["SiteID"]=> int(12)
                 ["BusinessDescription"]=> NULL
                 ["AdditionalImageURLs"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (0) { }
                 ["FacilitySquareFeet"]=> NULL
```

Does a response normally look like this? 
How do I go about getting the data in a formatted manner?

Comment: Confusing question. You've dumped the `$classes` variable, with is a PHP object, not a SOAP response. What are you trying to do? The actual SOAP response is some complex XML. Formatting it nicely doesn't achieve much, except maybe for debugged purposes.

Comment: What you have is an object with a sub object and sub-arrays.  After reformatting it above, does it look more sensible? Start with `$classes->GetClassesResult->Classes->Class[0]->Clients`, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your classes like this:

```
foreach ($classes->GetClassesResult->Classes->Class as $class) {
    // ... do your stuff here
    print_r($class);
}
```